# Was Rand al'Thor supposed to be a symbol for Jesus?

Tags: symbolism, religion, robert-jordan, wheel-of-time, brandon-sanderson

Rand al'Thor has several moments that could be considered "biblical", including (spoilers):

> "redeeming" mankind by cleansing Saidin", Dying to save the world, and being reborn after death, etc

Has Robert Jordan ever commented on this? I am really looking for a quote by either Robert Jordan or Brandon Sanderson, rather than a passage from a book.

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/117792/4918 "In-universe, is Aslan actually Jesus?"

Comment: Shouldn't the lord himself answer this? @Rand al'Thor

Comment: @RaisingAgent I know I would if someone was offering to deify me.....

Comment: @RaisingAgent I'd love to, but it looks like CHEESE has it covered.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I know people campaign to be mods, but *jeez*, isn't this taking it a little far? ;)

Answer (score 15):

From an interview [here:](http://www.theoryland.com/intvsresults.php?kwt=%27christianity%27)

> **Q**: How much of Jesus Christ is there in Rand? We have the wounded palms, side wound, crown of swords... How representational of Jesus Christ is Rand?
>
> **ROBERT JORDAN**: Rand has some elements of Jesus Christ, yes. But he is intended more to be a general "messiah figure." An archetype such as Arthur, rather than a manifestation of Jesus Christ in any way.

Also:

> **QUESTION**:
>   Is Rand al'Thor meant to be a Jesus figure?
>
> **ROBERT JORDAN**:
>   Um, if you consider King Arthur to be a Jesus figure—the king who must die.

A number of other interviews state that the Wheel of Time takes influences from many different religions, including the Bible.  This is also evident in [many of the Forsaken's names](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/2209/481) (Ishamael, Aginor, etc.) as well as the name of the Dark One.

He also draws from Islam and Judaism (same source as above) and

> Celtic myths and Norse myths and African and Middle-Eastern, and Hindu and Chinese and Japanese and Native American and even Australian Aboriginal.([source](http://www.theoryland.com/intvsresults.php?kw=hindu))

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I assume this was downvoted because of the many authorial quotes. However, those are accompanied by a solid explanation, so +1 from me.